# Having an issue with a Monte Carlo Simulations

Tags: python, io, montecarlo

I'm developing a Monte Carlo simulation for Magic: the Gathering. Currently the goal is simply to determine the probability of making land drops on curve. This can be calculated through Hypergeometric Distribution, but the possibilities of a further developed simulation could provide more insight, such as factoring in mana rocks or card draw effects, etc. However, for right now I'm testing for land drops, and I can use Cumulative Mass Distribution to confirm the results of my simulation.

### Algorithm

1. Simulate 10 decks of differing land amounts (31-40)

   1. Load Deck object
   2. Simulate 1,000,000 games with that deck

      1. Create Zone object
      2. Start game
      3. Set Library attribute to loaded Deck object
      4. Draw an opening hand of 7 cards
      5. Simulate 10 turns

         1. Draw a card, if able
         2. Play a land, if able
         3. Play as many cards as able
            4. Discard cards if hand size greater than 7
         4. Report Zones.get_battlefield_land_count()
      6. Record [turn#, bf_land_count]
   3. Analyze and clean data

      1. For deck, count number of times x = y for each turn
      2. convert to probability (divide by number of simulations run)
   4. Record cleaned data
2. Record data for each deck
3. Print results

Simply put, the output should be a table where x = turn # (1-10), and y = the # of lands in the deck (31-40)

From all my debugging and testing, individual simulations seem to run just fine. However, every time I run the debug testing code the simulation fails to run properly after the 6th iteration, regardless of the deck. After the 6th iteration, it seems to fail to load decks properly.

[image]

I've tested every method on an individual call and verified. It seems to be an issue with the number of simulations being run. Specifically regarding how it's not reading the files fast enough. I am not very familiar with this kind of optimization. It shouldn't be an issue with system memory as I have 32GB.

Relevant code:

```
def load_deck(f):
    '''
    Creates Deck object from a given filename (.csv format)
    
    Parameters
    ----------
    f : str
        File name to load from. Must be .csv file
        
    Variables
    ---------
    d : Deck
        Placeholder Deck object to build
        
    Returns
    -------
    d : Deck
        Built Deck object
    '''
    d = Deck()
    data = open(f).read()
    reader = csv.reader(io.StringIO(data))
    for row in reader:
        d.add_card(cc.Card(str(row[0]), int(row[1])))
    
    return d
```

Ultimately I want to run 100,000 simulations (or more) of each deck to get a good amount a data so that the Law of Large Numbers can take over and determine accurate probabilities.

**current output:**
[image]

**desired output (this is using CMD):**
[image]

Comment: the issue could be becasue of the file input/output (I/O) operations,  specifically, when running simulations with a large number of iterations, file I/O operations might be a bottleneck that could slow down the overall performance of the code.

Comment: please try `import numpy as np` followed by `data = np.loadtxt(f, delimiter=',', dtype=str)` instead of `data = open(f).read()` in your function... and then `cards = np.array([cc.Card(name, int(count)) for name, count in data])` and `d.add_cards(cards)` before returning `d`

Comment: (1) Try to print `d` just before `return d` to check if it looks normally. (2) Adding appropriate `__repr__` and `__str__` methods to `cc.Card` and maybe `Deck` could be helpful. (3) Explicitly closing a file is safer (but probably not the reason of the problem here).